# Why does Android Intent back to original Activity sometimes crash the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This bug has been tricky to find for me because when I initially start the Main Activity and press the help button, which begins an `Intent` to start the Help Activity, there is no problem.  Likewise, in the Help Activity pressing the button I made to go back, which starts an Intent for the main activity works fine.

However, after the user plays the game and gets a game over screen and returns from the high scores screen, then *sometimes* but not always pressing the help screen will cause the app to crash. Why is that? I imagine it has something to do with the activity life cycle, but seeing as I'm new to android development I must not be understanding it fully.

**Help class**

```
public class Help extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

        final ImageButton back = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.help, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

    private static final String TAG = "uVuMain";
    public SensorManager smanager;
    public Boolean playing = false, paused = false, firstPlay = true;
    public TextView score;
    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    long startTime, elapsedTime, lastUpdate;
    float moveIncrement, middle, moveRightLimit, moveLeftLimit, 
    difficulty;
    Timer timer;
    Boolean test = true;
    ScoreDB scoreDB;
    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        score.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        //get the sensor and music ready
        smanager = (SensorManager)this.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = assetManager.openFd("uVuLoop.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                    descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "could not load music: "+e.getMessage());
            mediaPlayer = null;
        }

        //mute option 
            final ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mute);
            ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.mute);
                    }
                    else {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        ib.setImageResource(R.drawable.unmute);
                    }
                }
            });

        //pause option
        //should not work if game hasn't started or if it's gameover
            final ImageButton pause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pause);
            pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    if (playing & !paused){
                        playing = false;
                        paused = true;
                        pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

                        //stop the background
                        //added for testing
                        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rl.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation.stop();

                        //stop the character animation
                        ImageView c = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainChar);
                        c.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal_0);

                        if (timer != null){
                            timer.pause();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!playing & paused) {
                        playing = true;
                        paused = false;
                        pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

                        //start the background
                        //added for testing
                        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
                        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rl.getBackground();
                        frameAnimation.start();

                        if (timer != null){
                            timer.resume();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            pause.setEnabled(false);

        //access to scoreboard for adding scores
        CursorFactory cf = null;
        scoreDB = new ScoreDB(this, "scoreDB", cf);

        final ImageButton help = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.help);
        help.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view){
                Intent h = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Help.class);
                startActivity(h);
            }
        });

        //start the game
        final ImageButton start = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {                
                CountDown timer = new CountDown(3000, 500);
                timer.start();
                pause.setEnabled(true);
                start.setEnabled(false);
                help.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });


    }

    //give the player a moment to get ready
    public class CountDown extends CountDownTimer{
        public CountDown(long s, long i){
            super(s, i);
        }
        ImageButton countDown = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            countDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.go);
            playing = true;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            score.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Start background animation
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
            rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
            AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rl.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();

            //Start Character animation
            ImageView mainChar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainChar);
            mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.maincharacter);

            //Make sure gameover screen is invisible
            ImageView gameOver = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gameover);
            gameOver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if (firstPlay){
                //Calculate screen movement 
                int[]posXY= new int[2];
                mainChar.getLocationInWindow(posXY);
                middle = posXY[0];
                //changed from .005 to .01 for faster start 
                moveIncrement = (float)(middle*.01); 
                moveRightLimit = (float) (middle+0.5*middle);
                moveLeftLimit= (float)(middle-0.5*middle);
                firstPlay = false;
            }
            mainChar.setX(middle);

            //Start the clock
            timer = new Timer(startTime);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            performTick(millisUntilFinished, countDown);
        }
    }

    public void performTick(long millisUntilFinished, ImageButton count){
        int remaining = Math.round(millisUntilFinished * 0.001f);
        if (remaining == 3){
            count.setImageResource(R.drawable.num_3);
        }
        else if (remaining == 2){
            count.setImageResource(R.drawable.num_2);
        }
        else if (remaining == 1){
            count.setImageResource(R.drawable.num_1);
        }
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
        if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER && playing){
            getAccelerometer(event);
        }
    }

    public void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event){
        //In intervals of 10 seconds increase the difficulty 
        elapsedTime = timer.getElapsedTime()/1000;
        difficulty = ((elapsedTime/10)+1);

        //only need the y axis and want avg for smoother controls
        float[]values = event.values;
        int orientation = Math.round(values[1]);
        orientation = smoothing(orientation);

        score.setText("Walked "+elapsedTime+" feet.\nLevel: "+difficulty);

        //Move across screen in a timed interval
        //Changed from 15 to 25
        if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastUpdate>25){
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            move(orientation, difficulty);      
        }
    }

    public void move(int oriented, float difficulty){
        //Get character's current position
        int[]posXY= new int[2];
        ImageView mainChar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainChar);
        mainChar.getLocationInWindow(posXY);
        int currentPosition = posXY[0];
        if (currentPosition > middle){

        }

        float delta = (float) (moveIncrement*difficulty*2);
        if (oriented>=0){
            if (oriented == 0){
                oriented = 1;
            }
            delta = delta*((float)oriented/10);
//          Check right boundary
            if ((currentPosition+delta)>moveRightLimit){
                mainChar.setX(moveRightLimit);
                mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.fall_right);
                gameOver();
            }
            else{
//          Log.d(TAG, "Oriented value: "+oriented+"\nDelta value: "+delta);
                mainChar.setX(currentPosition+delta);
                tilt(mainChar, currentPosition+delta);
            }

        }
        else {
            delta = -delta*((float)oriented/10);
//          Check left boundary
            if ((currentPosition-delta)<moveLeftLimit){
                mainChar.setX(moveLeftLimit);
                mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.fall_left);
                gameOver();
            }
            else {
//          Log.d(TAG, "Oriented value: "+oriented+"\nDelta value: "+delta);
                mainChar.setX(currentPosition-delta);
                tilt(mainChar, currentPosition-delta);
            }
        }
    }

    public void tilt(ImageView mainChar, float position){

            if (position< (middle-middle*.10)){
                mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.maincharacterleft); 
            }
            else if(position>(middle+middle*.10)){
                mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.maincharacterright);
            }
            else {
                mainChar.setImageResource(R.drawable.maincharacter);
            }
    }

    public void gameOver(){
        //stop the background
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rl.getBackground();
        frameAnimation.stop();

        //fade in the gameover screen
        Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        ImageView gameOver = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gameover);
        gameOver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gameOver.startAnimation(animation);

        //Reset buttons
        ImageButton startbtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);
        startbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_again);
        playing = false;
        ImageButton hlp = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.help);
        hlp.setEnabled(true);
        startbtn.setEnabled(true);

        //update scoreboard
        scoreDB.addScore((int) elapsedTime);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScoreBoard.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

    //take average of last 4 values to smooth controls
    private int smoothing(int value){
        ll.add(value);

        if (ll.size()>4){
            ll.removeFirst();
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (Integer i: ll){
            sum+=i;
        }

        int avg = Math.round(sum/((float)ll.size()));
        return avg;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }

        smanager.registerListener(this, 
        smanager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        smanager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        smanager.unregisterListener(this);

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            if (isFinishing()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I've been stumped on this and reading the Android docs on `Intent`s didn't seem to help.  On a possibly related note, if the music is muted, when I go back from the help screen it becomes un-muted. If this is related to my issue please let me know as well.

**Logcat**

```
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): Process: com.uVu.caffeineRun, PID: 27704
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uVu.caffeineRun/com.uVu.caffeineRun.Help}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at com.uVu.caffeineRun.Help.onCreate(Help.java:20)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    ... 11 more
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    ... 23 more
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
10-01 14:44:55.149: E/AndroidRuntime(27704):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Perhaps your MainActivity is being destroyed and recreated by the system and you are not handling that correctly? This is a tricky yet essential part of Android dev. Add some logging to onCreate() to see if it is being called again when you return to MainActivity.

Comment: Two things, first post the logcat and second, for the main activity you just given onCreate. While coming back from a top activity it's very unlikely that the onCreate get called again. So post the complete main activity code including other overrides if any.

Comment: Logcat please!! I believe it is mediaPlayer at onResume, you do not check the state on the player.

Comment: Where is your crash report?

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" You are using too much memory.

Comment: Added the logcat for everyone, and gnuanu I posted the full MainActivity  class, what do you think the overrides might be doing?  The thing is Code-Apprentice this doesnt seem to happen unless I press the phone's backbutton (I think) before running the app again, so I think Memory may be a part of it, but due to something else going wrong.